# What is the equivalent command of "mysql_real_escape_string" in Oracle?

Tags: php, mysql, oracle, zend-framework, pdo

I am trying to port a php file that is used with MySQL. My goal is to have this file working with Oracle instead of MySQL. I have gotten all of the connect string switched over. I am now stuck with finding an Oracle equivalent commands for:

`mysql_real_escape_string($string);`

Can someone tell me what it would be, or direct me to somewhere that will tell me. Thanks!

I gave an attempt to `PDO::quote` and `PDO::prepare` and it says that `Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object` for both prepare and object. The whole purpose of this is to get TightURL to work directly from my web server. My web server uses Oracle, not MySQL so I am having to convert the main php file to work with Oracle.

I attempted it on a WAMP server with MySQL and it worked great, but when I try to use the prepare or quote for Oracle I get that error above.

Comment: While you're at it you could modify it to use parametrized queries instead of `*_escape()`ing like it's the 90s

Comment: What do you use to connect to Oracle? ODBC? PDO?

Comment: I am using `Zend_Db::factory('PDO_OCI'` to connect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using PDO to connect to Oracle, the function would be [PDO::quote](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php). Note that `PDO::quote` places quotes around strings while `mysql_real_escape_string` does not.

Having said that, it would be best to use prepared statements instead of string concatenation to issue SQL statements. From the manual:

> If you are using this function to build SQL statements, you are
>   strongly recommended to use PDO::prepare() to prepare SQL statements
>   with bound parameters instead of using PDO::quote() to interpolate
>   user input into an SQL statement. Prepared statements with bound
>   parameters are not only more portable, more convenient, immune to SQL
>   injection, but are often much faster to execute than interpolated
>   queries, as both the server and client side can cache a compiled form
>   of the query.